# How do i redirect different site visitors based on ip address?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, ip, ip-address

I would like to redirect every user that visited my site to different url each. I'm limiting it to ten sites only though. For example;

When visitor 1 visit my website; [www.youarelovely.com](http://www.youarelovely.com) it would open.

When visitor 2 visit my website; [www.youarelovely.com](http://www.youarelovely.com) the visitor would be redirected to [www.youarelovely.com/1](http://www.youarelovely.com/1)

When visitor 3 visit my website; [www.youarelovely.com](http://www.youarelovely.com) the visitor would be redirected to [www.youarelovely.com/2](http://www.youarelovely.com/2) etc... to 10.

I feel by detecting user IP address, storing it in a text file, then getting the next visitor ip address and search it in the list of visitor stored ip address, if it's there then the user would be redirected to that url, if not then the user would be directed to the next available url. How can i achieve it via pure html and javascript?

NOTE: This is for a proof of concept project that would be deployed on github pages or codepen. So basically we're not in the business of complicating things, and it's not location based redirecting because all the visitors would be in the same location, hence why the redirecting solution need to be base on IP address only.

```
var defaultCountry = ‘US’;
var defaultSite = ‘https://google.com';
var otherSite = ‘https://google.co.uk';
fetch(‘https://ipapi.co/country/')
 .then(response => {
   if (response.ok) {
     return response.text();
   } else {
     throw new Error(‘HTTP Error ‘ + response.status);
   }
 })
 .then(country => {
   if (country == defaultCountry) {
     // No action needed - already on the default site
     console.log(‘Already on default site’);
   } else {
     // Redirect rest of the world
     console.log(‘Redirecting to country specific website’);
     window.location = otherSite;
   }
 })
 .catch(function(error) {
   // Network error
   // Script blocked by browser extension
   // 429 error (too many requests)
   console.log(error);
 });
```

Comment: I would like to ask the purpose of doing this. If you just wanted to make sure that different visitor are redirected to different sites, then I would suggest to look onto FingerprintJS

Comment: Wow never heard of that, this looks really promising and ideal for what i want, so how do I implement it using FingprintJS? @JoshuaOoi

Comment: FingerprintJS basically provides a unique identifier for each unique visitor, you may just compare the generated identifier to a database and check if it's exist or not, if exists, then nagivate to previous assigned URL, if not, assign a URL and store it to database. 
You may check [their documentation](https://github.com/fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs) for more info on using the library.